# Downloading a Wiki Page from BitBucket as PDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, wiki, bitbucket

How can I save a Wiki Page (WikiOhana using Creole) of a BitBucket repository as PDF? I read the documentation but I think it's not possible (at least directly).

In case it's not possible. What other option would you recommend to share the wiki as a document?

I'm using OS X Lion and Windows 7.

Comment: Can you retrieve this wiki page over the internet? If so, process it using `wkhtmltopdf` - you may even be able to process it directly, rather than having to retrieve the page (plus all its asset files) yourself. (Generally it is a good idea to specify what platform you are on, to save people having to ask. Thankfully `wkhtmltopdf` is available for all platforms!).

Comment: BitBucket uses WikiOhana + Creole for its Wikis. I will try with wkhtmltopdf. Thanks!

Comment: No, I mean what OS/platform are _you_ on? Windows? Linux? etc.

Comment: Great. Give my recommendation a go, and ping here if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

- Clone wiki (top right button on bitbucket wiki). All the wiki pages are saved as md files
- Use some online tool to convert MD to PDF (ie https://md2pdf.netlify.com/ )

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to open it with Safari or Chrome, using the developer tool to remove the left navigation panel, header, footer of the wiki page and export it as PDF.

1. Right click and choose "Inspect element", then choose the
   navigation/header/footer nodes and remove them.
2. Export current HTML page to PDF from browser's file menu.